# package name with '_' as prefix in node_modules directory

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

The files in node_modules cannot work in my environment: doing ng build will show errors in @types/jquery. I know what is causing this problem, finding the name of package in node_modules is not correct(I think ,maybe wrong).
The package name is like this:

[The package name`s prefix is "_XXX"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCjiQ.png)

I build my angular2-MVC project and tell me d.ts in @type/jquery is error.
I got another node_modules,like this:
[correct package name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9fdY.png)

Yes, it work fine for building.
So, what`s the issue is?

Comment: I've never heard of an underscope prefix causing build errors with TypeScript. Maybe you're seeing a tslint warning?

Comment: The snapscreen is not show, I type it here:not correct name    
   __zone.js@0.8.16@zone.js,       noticing the prefix "_".       The correct package name is like this zone.js@0.8.16@zone.js